# Cannot upgrade ubuntu from 19.10 to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 19.10

I cannot upgrade ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04 LTS.When I try to upgrade via the terminal,this is the output:

```
    salil@salil-latitude-e6430:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
[sudo] password for salil: 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [1,554 B]                                         
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,342 kB]                                                  
Fetched 1,343 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
authenticate 'focal.tar.gz' against 'focal.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'focal.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease                         
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease                 
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease                  
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
salil@salil-latitude-e6430:~$
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: there is some similar [issue here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1849669) including a solution. You could try...

Comment: I have tried the commands they have mentioned.It still gives the same result.Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @DevaSalilSonyRani, have you tried `do-release-upgrade -d`?

Comment: @Ollie Yes I had tried but it didn't work.So I formatted the hdd and installed 20.04 as new.Thank you for the suggestion.